# OpenTK error, Unable to load DLL 'libGLES.dll

Tags: dll, opentk

So I just got started with OpenTK, and have this code in a class that subclasses the `GameWindow` class:

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnRenderFrame(e);
    int val = (int)ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit;
    GL.Clear(val);
    this.SwapBuffers();
}
```

On calling `GL.Clear(val)`, I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in OpenTK.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'libGLES.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I installed OpenTK using the nuget addon manager, and as a measure to try to solve this error I've downloaded the installer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opentk/files/latest/download) and tried installing it by that.

I will continue to try to find the issue tomorrow, if no one has any pointers by then I'll hopefully be able to add to the internet knowledge, Q & A style.

Answer (score 3):

I auto-added the reference using the ctrl + . command in vs, and didn't bother to check the namespace added.

The namespace added was using OpenTK.Graphics.ES10; (Embedded standard), I ofc wanted using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

Switching this reference solved the problem.